# PyArrow Table: Cast a Struct within a ListArray column to a new schema

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have a parquet file with a struct field in a ListArray column where the data type of a field within the struct changed from an int to float with some new data.

In order to combine the new and old data i had been reading the active & historical parquet files in with `pq.read_table` and then using `pa.concat_table` to combine and write the new file.

So to make the schema of the two tables compatible before concatenating i do the following:

```
active = pq.read_table("path\to\active\parquet")
active_schema = active.schema

hist = pq.read_table("path\to\hist\parquet")
hist = hist.cast(target_schema=active_schema)

combined = pa.concat_tables([active, hist])
```

But I get the folowing error when casting:

```
ArrowNotImplementedError: Unsupported cast from struct<code: string, unit_price: struct<amount: int64, currency: string>, line_total: struct<amount: int64, currency: string>, reversal: bool, include_for: list<item: string>, quantity: int64, seats: int64, units: int64, percentage: int64> to struct using function cast_struct
```

Based on this it seems i wont be able to do the cast.

So my question is, how can I go about merging these datasets / how can I update the schema on the old table?  I'm trying to stay within the arrow / parquet ecosystem if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately casting a struct to a similar struct type but with different field type is not yet implemented (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1888 for the feature request). I think currently the only possible workaround is to extract the struct column, cast the fields separately, recreate the struct column from that and update the table with that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately casting a struct to a similar struct type but with different field type is not yet implemented (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1888 for the feature request).

I think currently the only possible workaround is to extract the struct column, cast the fields separately, recreate the struct column from that and update the table with that.

A small example of this workflow, starting from the following table with the struct column:

```py
>>> table = pa.table({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, None, {'a':3, 'b':4}]})
>>> table
pyarrow.Table
col1: int64
col2: struct<a: int64, b: int64>
  child 0, a: int64
  child 1, b: int64
```

and assume the following target schema (where one field of the struct column is changed from int to float):

```py
>>> new_schema = pa.schema([('col1', pa.int64()), ('col2', pa.struct([('a', pa.int64()), ('b', pa.float64())]))])
>>> new_schema
col1: int64
col2: struct<a: int64, b: double>
  child 0, a: int64
  child 1, b: double
```

Then the workaround looks like:

```py
# cast fields separately
struct_col = table["col2"]
new_struct_type = new_schema.field("col2").type
new_fields = [field.cast(typ_field.type) for field, typ_field in zip(struct_col.flatten(), new_struct_type)]
# create new structarray from separate fields
import pyarrow.compute as pc
new_struct_array = pc.make_struct(*new_fields, field_names=[f.name for f in new_struct_type])
# replace the table column with the new array
col_idx = table.schema.get_field_index("col2")
new_table = table.set_column(col_idx, new_schema.field("col2"), new_struct_array)

>>> new_table
pyarrow.Table
col1: int64
col2: struct<a: int64, b: double>
  child 0, a: int64
  child 1, b: double
```

Comment: thank you @joris for the detailed explanation.  I believe that would have worked, however, when trying to implement i realized that it was actually a struct within a ListArray column, not an actual Struct column.  As a result, creating the `new_fields` fails since the ListArray schema type isnt iterable.  I updated my question to reflect the actual situation.  If you have any additional insight would be greatly appreciated!